# Django: Login_required(redirect to custom login_url) not working

Tags: django, authentication, login-required

views.py file

```
@login_required(login_url='frontpage')
def dash(request):
    events = Event.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = createEventForm(request.POST)
        args = {'form':form , 'events':events}
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html',args)
    else:
        form = createEventForm()
        args = {'form':form , 'events':events}
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html',args)
```

urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', frontviews.login),
    path('', frontviews.login, name = "login"),
    url(r'frontpage^/$', frontviews.login, name = "frontpage"),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', dashviews.dash, name = "dashboard"),#require login to fix
    url(r'^$', dashviews.logout, name = "logout"),
    url(r'^forum/$', forumviews.forumpage, name = 'forum'),
    url(r'^events/$', dashviews.EventPage, name = 'events'),
]
```

I want the user to be required to login from the frontpage(of website), i.e. i want to redirect user to frontpage if he tries to use url[website.com/dashboard] to directly enter dashboard.
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You haven’t said how it isn’t working. What happens when you go to `/dashboard/` without logging in first?

Comment: The problem could be your regex. Change `r'frontpage^/$'` to `r'^frontpage/$'`. The `^` matches the beginning of the string so it doesn’t make sense to have it in the middle of the regex.

Comment: @Alasdair sir it goes to dashboard doesnt require login

Comment: @Alasdair i changed it from r'frontpage^/$' to r'^frontpage/$'. it was by mistake, but thanks. STILL IT IS NOT WORKING CORRECTLY, JUST AS BEFORE

Comment: @Alasdair clearing cache, changing browser didnt work

Comment: You seem to be using `login_required` correctly. Perhaps you aren’t running the code you think you are. Make sure you have saved any changes to your files, checked in/pushed/pulled any changes in git, and restarted the Django server.

Comment: Note you have three urls that use `url(r'^$', ...)` or `path('', ...)`. Django will always use the first URL pattern and ignore the other two. Therefore you can’t log out at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change url of the frontpage.
Your wrong url

```
url(r'frontpage^/$', frontviews.login, name = "frontpage"),
```

The below url is correct.

```
url(r'^frontpage/$', frontviews.login, name = "frontpage"),
```

The ^ matches the beginning of the string. so it doesn’t use other position of the url.